# KendoUI grid edit popup, how to hide field in grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui grid and I only want to show a sub-set of fields in the grid. However, all fields on the entity should show in the popup editor. I would prefer not creating a custom editor but using the one that kendo provides by default. Is there a decorator I can attach to fields to make them hidden in the grid but visible in the popup editor?

Answer (score 8):

Add to the column definition in the grid the attribute [`hidden`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.hidden) and set it to `true`

```
columns   : [
    { field: "Id", width: 90, hidden: true },
    { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
    { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" },
    { field: "Title", width: 90, title: "Title", hidden: true },
    { field: "Age", width: 50 }
]
```